# ¿Cómo generar búsquedas de Mysql a partir de select option?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de mostrar datos específicos a partir de la selección de un Select Option en PHP, pero siempre que que selecciono las opciones me muestra todos los resultados de la tabla.
Aquí el código que recibe las selecciones del formulario:

```
 <?php
 include 'conexion.php';
 $consulta = "";

 if(isset($_GET['sexo']) AND $_GET['sexo'] != "Cualquiera"){
     $consulta  ="sexo LIKE '%".$_GET['sexo']."%' AND ";
 }
 if(isset($_GET['edad']) AND $_GET['edad'] != "edad"){
     $consulta .= "edad LIKE '%".$_GET['edad']."%' AND ";
 }
 if(isset($_GET['delito']) AND $_GET['delito'] != "Cualquiera"){
     $consulta .="delito like '%".$_GET['delito']."%' AND ";
 }
 if(isset($_GET['alcaldia']) AND $_GET['alcaldia'] != "Cualquiera"){
     $consulta .="alcaldia like '%".$_GET['alcaldia']."%' AND ";
 }
 if($consulta != ""){
    $consulta=substr($consulta,0,(strlen($consulta)-4));
 }
 ?>
```

En seguida la tabla donde muestro los resultados:

```
 <h1 align="center">RESULTADOS BUSQUEDA ESPECÍFICA</h1><br>
 <?php while($row = $resultados->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
 <div class="gallery-container">
     <div class="gallery-item"><img src= "<?php echo $row['ruta'];?>" 
 width="198" height="222">
     <center><p><?php echo $row['folio']; ?></p></center>
     <?php echo "<center><p><a href='mostrarficha.php? 
 id_registro=".$row['id_registro']."'>Consultar</a></p></center>";?> 
    </div>
 </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: A esas consultas les falta el select, from y where: SELECT * FROM laTabla WHERE...

Comment: Además lo de quitar los últimos 4 caracteres es un poco chapucilla jejeje, eso lo arreglas quitando el  " AND" del final y poniéndolo al principio " AND " en todas menos en la primera.

Comment: ¿Qué tal si nos dejas un dataset con unos registros de ejemplo para que podamos reproducir el fallo? También estaría genial si nos aportaras unos valores a los `$_GET` con los resultados esperados para las pruebas... En definitiva, montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)